# How to describe Past situation in answer?

Tags: past-tense

Why you left your boyfriend?

Which answer is correct and why?

> a) He was already having a girlfriend.
>  b) He had already had a girlfriend. 
>  c) He already had a girlfriend.
> d) He already had had a girlfriend.

Comment: just a note - "Why you left your boyfriend?" is not a question. "Why did you leave your boyfriend?" would be. Alternatively, "Tell me why you left your boyfriend."

Comment: Please give your own guesses and provide your own reasoning when posing questions, otherwise they might look like homework help requests.

Answer (score 2):

C is correct: He already had a girlfriend.

And just for good measure, the question should actually be phrased "why *did you leave* your boyfriend?"

Although those both said, this seems like an odd setup. If he already had a girlfriend, that seems like he shouldn't have been "left." Are you sure you aren't looking for something more along the lines of "Why did you two not start dating?" for the question, or "he cheated on me" for the answer? Those might make it make more sense.